VSCode Typescript debug does not open local file but creates another one on NX Nest Project
I have a NX nestjs application running on a docker container. I have setup this task on launch.json
 {
      "name": "Attach to my-app-api",
      "request": "attach",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 6661,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/app",
      "restart": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node",
      "sourceMaps": true
    },

I can attach to the session and see logs on the Terminal.

The problem I have is that the breakpoints I set on my project files are not being carried to the debug session.
If I click the mapped file from the terminal log, and set a breakpoint there it works. I realized it is something like a copy of the file I am trying to debug:

I would expect VS Code links my file when debugging.
My docker compose attaches the workspace into the app folder
my-api-local:
    container_name: my-app-api
    image: node:20.11.0
    tty: true
    working_dir: /app
    user: ${DOCKER_USER}
    volumes:
      - ../..:/app
      - ${NPM_CACHE}:/.npm
    command: npx nx run my-app-api"
    networks:
      - local-dev-net
    ports:
      - 3334:3334
      - 6661:6661 # Debug port


When I run the debug session, the Debug diagnostics shows my file found on my MAC root folder
✅ This breakpoint was initially set in:

/Users/distante/dev/org/my-project/libs/my-app/nestjs/search/feature/src/lib/search/search.controller.ts line 40 column 1

❓ We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name:

/Users/distante/libs/my-app/nestjs/search/feature/src/lib/search/search.controller.ts
If this is the same file, you may need to adjust your build tool to correct the paths.

If I added an override to launch.json
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///*": "/*"
      }

It search for the file on the root...
✅ This breakpoint was initially set in:

/Users/distante/dev/org/my-project/libs/my-app/nestjs/search/feature/src/lib/search/search.controller.ts line 40 column 1

❓ We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name:

/libs/my-app/nestjs/search/feature/src/lib/search/search.controller.ts
If this is the same file, you may need to adjust your build tool to correct the paths.

If I map it to "webpack:///*": "${workspaceFolder}/*" the first problem appear again.
I am now lost...

This is a bug on NX and the nest lib. A workaround is given in this open issue
You have to update the project webpack config to map the generated mapped to the correct place.
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nrwl/webpack')
const path = require('path')

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), (config) => {
  // Update the webpack config as needed here.
  // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`
  config.output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate = function (info) {
    const rel = path.relative(process.cwd(), info.absoluteResourcePath)
    return `webpack:///./${rel}`
  }
  return config
})

